# trying to make prediction in keras without knowing the correct answer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a question. I've got trained model, but the thing is I don't actually know how to make a real prediction with that. Output looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDtS4.png). But I wanna have a DataFrame for prediction only for a couple days ahead without knowing the actual future data to compare with.

here is the code

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 4:-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]
#dataset shape = (7069, 13)

split = int(len(dataset)*0.8)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:split], X[split:], y[:split], y[split:]

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

classifier = keras.models.load_model('C:\\model')



y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
dataset['y_pred'] = np.NaN
dataset.iloc[(len(dataset) - len(y_pred)):,-1:] = y_pred
trade_dataset = dataset.dropna()

trade_dataset['Tomorrows Returns'] = 0.
trade_dataset['Tomorrows Returns'] = np.log(trade_dataset['Close']/trade_dataset['Close'].shift(1))
trade_dataset['Tomorrows Returns'] = trade_dataset['Tomorrows Returns'].shift(-1)


trade_dataset['Strategy Returns'] = 0.
trade_dataset['Strategy Returns'] = np.where(trade_dataset['y_pred'] == True, trade_dataset['Tomorrows Returns'], - trade_dataset['Tomorrows Returns'])

trade_dataset['Cumulative Market Returns'] = np.cumsum(trade_dataset['Tomorrows Returns'])
trade_dataset['Cumulative Strategy Returns'] = np.cumsum(trade_dataset['Strategy Returns'])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(trade_dataset['Cumulative Market Returns'], color='r', label='Market Returns')
plt.plot(trade_dataset['Cumulative Strategy Returns'], color='g', label='Strategy Returns')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this does what you want.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
from collections import deque

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import os
import random


# set seed, so we can get the same results after rerunning several times
np.random.seed(314)
tf.random.set_seed(314)
random.seed(314)



def load_data(ticker, n_steps=50, scale=True, shuffle=True, lookup_step=1, 
                test_size=0.2, feature_columns=['adjclose', 'volume', 'open', 'high', 'low']):
    # see if ticker is already a loaded stock from yahoo finance
    if isinstance(ticker, str):
        # load it from yahoo_fin library
        df = si.get_data(ticker)
    elif isinstance(ticker, pd.DataFrame):
        # already loaded, use it directly
        df = ticker
    # this will contain all the elements we want to return from this function
    result = {}
    # we will also return the original dataframe itself
    result['df'] = df.copy()
    # make sure that the passed feature_columns exist in the dataframe
    for col in feature_columns:
        assert col in df.columns, f"'{col}' does not exist in the dataframe."
    if scale:
        column_scaler = {}
        # scale the data (prices) from 0 to 1
        for column in feature_columns:
            scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
            df[column] = scaler.fit_transform(np.expand_dims(df[column].values, axis=1))
            column_scaler[column] = scaler

        # add the MinMaxScaler instances to the result returned
        result["column_scaler"] = column_scaler
    # add the target column (label) by shifting by `lookup_step`
    df['future'] = df['adjclose'].shift(-lookup_step)
    # last `lookup_step` columns contains NaN in future column
    # get them before droping NaNs
    last_sequence = np.array(df[feature_columns].tail(lookup_step))
    # drop NaNs
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    sequence_data = []
    sequences = deque(maxlen=n_steps)
    for entry, target in zip(df[feature_columns].values, df['future'].values):
        sequences.append(entry)
        if len(sequences) == n_steps:
            sequence_data.append([np.array(sequences), target])
    # get the last sequence by appending the last `n_step` sequence with `lookup_step` sequence
    # for instance, if n_steps=50 and lookup_step=10, last_sequence should be of 59 (that is 50+10-1) length
    # this last_sequence will be used to predict in future dates that are not available in the dataset
    last_sequence = list(sequences) + list(last_sequence)
    # shift the last sequence by -1
    last_sequence = np.array(pd.DataFrame(last_sequence).shift(-1).dropna())
    # add to result
    result['last_sequence'] = last_sequence
    # construct the X's and y's
    X, y = [], []
    for seq, target in sequence_data:
        X.append(seq)
        y.append(target)
    # convert to numpy arrays
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    # reshape X to fit the neural network
    X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[2], X.shape[1]))
    # split the dataset
    result["X_train"], result["X_test"], result["y_train"], result["y_test"] = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, shuffle=shuffle)
    # return the result
    return result

def create_model(sequence_length, units=256, cell=LSTM, n_layers=2, dropout=0.3,
                loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer="rmsprop", bidirectional=False):
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(n_layers):
        if i == 0:
            # first layer
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(None, sequence_length)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, sequence_length)))
        elif i == n_layers - 1:
            # last layer
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=False)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=False))
        else:
            # hidden layers
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=True)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=True))
        # add dropout after each layer
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
    model.compile(loss=loss, metrics=["mean_absolute_error"], optimizer=optimizer)
    return model


# Window size or the sequence length
N_STEPS = 100
# Lookup step, 1 is the next day
LOOKUP_STEP = 1
# test ratio size, 0.2 is 20%
TEST_SIZE = 0.2
# features to use
FEATURE_COLUMNS = ["adjclose", "volume", "open", "high", "low"]
# date now
date_now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
### model parameters
N_LAYERS = 3
# LSTM cell
CELL = LSTM
# 256 LSTM neurons
UNITS = 256
# 40% dropout
DROPOUT = 0.4
# whether to use bidirectional RNNs
BIDIRECTIONAL = False
### training parameters
# mean absolute error loss
# LOSS = "mae"
# huber loss
LOSS = "huber_loss"
OPTIMIZER = "adam"
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 10


# save the dataframe
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

start_date = date(2019, 6,30)
end_date = date(2020, 6, 30)
days = np.busday_count(start_date, end_date)



# Apple stock market
ticker = "AAPL"
ticker_data_filename = os.path.join("data", f"{ticker}_{date_now}.csv")
# model name to save, making it as unique as possible based on parameters
model_name = f"{date_now}_{ticker}-{LOSS}-{OPTIMIZER}-{CELL.__name__}-seq-{N_STEPS}-step-{LOOKUP_STEP}-layers-{N_LAYERS}-units-{UNITS}"
if BIDIRECTIONAL:
    model_name += "-b"


# create these folders if they does not exist
if not os.path.isdir("results"):
    os.mkdir("results")
if not os.path.isdir("logs"):
    os.mkdir("logs")
if not os.path.isdir("data"):
    os.mkdir("data")
    

# load the data
data = load_data(ticker, N_STEPS, lookup_step=LOOKUP_STEP, test_size=TEST_SIZE, feature_columns=FEATURE_COLUMNS)

# save the dataframe
data["df"].to_csv(ticker_data_filename)

# construct the model
model = create_model(N_STEPS, loss=LOSS, units=UNITS, cell=CELL, n_layers=N_LAYERS,
                    dropout=DROPOUT, optimizer=OPTIMIZER, bidirectional=BIDIRECTIONAL)

# some tensorflow callbacks
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join("results", model_name + ".h5"), save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join("logs", model_name))

history = model.fit(data["X_train"], data["y_train"],
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    validation_data=(data["X_test"], data["y_test"]),
                    callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard],
                    verbose=1)

model.save(os.path.join("results", model_name) + ".h5")


# after the model ends running...or during training, run this
# tensorboard --logdir="logs"
# http://localhost:6006/


data = load_data(ticker, N_STEPS, lookup_step=LOOKUP_STEP, test_size=TEST_SIZE,
                feature_columns=FEATURE_COLUMNS, shuffle=False)

# construct the model
model = create_model(N_STEPS, loss=LOSS, units=UNITS, cell=CELL, n_layers=N_LAYERS,
                    dropout=DROPOUT, optimizer=OPTIMIZER, bidirectional=BIDIRECTIONAL)

model_path = os.path.join("results", model_name) + ".h5"
model.load_weights(model_path)


# evaluate the model
mse, mae = model.evaluate(data["X_test"], data["y_test"], verbose=0)
# calculate the mean absolute error (inverse scaling)
mean_absolute_error = data["column_scaler"]["adjclose"].inverse_transform([[mae]])[0][0]
print("Mean Absolute Error:", mean_absolute_error)

def predict(model, data, classification=False):
    # retrieve the last sequence from data
    last_sequence = data["last_sequence"][:N_STEPS]
    # retrieve the column scalers
    column_scaler = data["column_scaler"]
    # reshape the last sequence
    last_sequence = last_sequence.reshape((last_sequence.shape[1], last_sequence.shape[0]))
    # expand dimension
    last_sequence = np.expand_dims(last_sequence, axis=0)
    # get the prediction (scaled from 0 to 1)
    prediction = model.predict(last_sequence)
    # get the price (by inverting the scaling)
    predicted_price = column_scaler["adjclose"].inverse_transform(prediction)[0][0]
    return predicted_price


# predict the future price
future_price = predict(model, data)
print(f"Future price after {LOOKUP_STEP} days is ${future_price:.2f}")
```

These is some more code here.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/TensorFlow%20-%20Stock%20Price%20Prediction.ipynb